# Interpretation of fixed effect coefficients for binary predictors with an unusual DV

Tags: mixed-model, interpretation, model, lme4-nlme

I am new to R however, with some help from a colleague I have constructed my first random intercept mixed model using the lme4 package. The DV is AFL draft order (where being selected earlier in the draft is a better result). Given this, I am having trouble interpreting the results and particularly the direction for the fixed effect coefficients.

```
Fixed effects:
                     Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            36.234      1.422  11.990  25.477 8.26e-12 ***
Mature.or.non.mature   14.001      3.957 311.400   3.538 0.000464 ***
Under18.All.Aus       -15.381      2.343 311.830  -6.565 2.17e-10 ***
Indigenous             -7.478      3.702 307.360  -2.020 0.044261 *
```

The variables were originally coded like this...

- Non mature = 0, mature = 1
- Not selected in under18 all aus = 0, selected = 1
- Non indigenous = 0, indigenous = 1

Is the coefficient for maturity (given it is positive) suggesting that being more mature (defined by being >20 years of age) results in being selected later in the draft? But then I get confused with the under 8 all aus coefficient with it being negative.

Could someone please help me with this interpretation?

Comment: Can you provide more information? You state that you have an "unusual DV", but what is it & how does that impact your question? I don't see anything specific to mixed models / lme4 here? Your situation is rather opaque to me.

Comment: The DV is draft order as stated in the initial question and I am looking for help with the interpretation of the fixed effect coefficients. What is the additional info that you require specifically?

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Is your response / DV an ordinal variable? Can you paste your code & complete output?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the same as the standard R output for linear regressions, then you are right about maturity. And it appears that being selected in under18 all aus leads to an earlier draft pick, and being indigenous also leads to an earlier draft pick.